# Create adaptive cards using npm package

Tags: node.js, botframework, adaptive-cards

I recently discovered the adaptivecards npm package. I will be needing this to perform CSS customizations, which will be different for every card. The documentation does not, however specify how to create a card. An instance is created as follows:

```
var adaptiveCard = new AdaptiveCards.AdaptiveCard();
```

Following this, a JSON containing the actual adaptive card content is parsed:

```
adaptiveCard.parse(card);
```

My question is, how can I create adaptive cards, and apply custom CSS to it, and be able to send it on the botframework emulator?

Comment: Bot cards are rendered  by each channel cliets. If you want your own style or outlooking, you need to overwrite the render functionalities in the clients and rebuild them, like botframework emulator, botframework web chat...

Comment: Is there a guide I can follow to achieve this?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat